# Crash enabling glsl extension with mismatched driver version

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm currently having an issue on the nexus 6 that causes an OpenGL crash when compiling a shader. My shader enables the GL_OES_standard_derivatives extension by following the procedure of checking if the extension is #defined which then crashes during glCompileShader. The device does support the extension and works correctly on other android/iOS devices and versions.

Has anyone else come across this problem and found a solution/alternate work around?

**Stack trace**

```
03-18 12:41:26.350: I/DEBUG(343): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-18 12:41:26.350: I/DEBUG(343): Build fingerprint: 'google/shamu/shamu:5.0/LRX21O/1570415:user/release-keys'
03-18 12:41:26.350: I/DEBUG(343): Revision: '33696'
03-18 12:41:26.350: I/DEBUG(343): ABI: 'arm'
03-18 12:41:26.350: I/DEBUG(343): pid: 17572, tid: 17613, name: Render Thread  >>> com.ninjakiwi.monkeycity <<<
03-18 12:41:26.351: I/DEBUG(343): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x11
03-18 12:41:26.405: I/DEBUG(343):     r0 9ec5f900  r1 00000031  r2 9ec8aa00  r3 00000000
03-18 12:41:26.405: I/DEBUG(343):     r4 9ecccd80  r5 00000002  r6 00000000  r7 ab474f50
03-18 12:41:26.405: I/DEBUG(343):     r8 00000000  r9 00000001  sl 9ee00744  fp 00000001
03-18 12:41:26.405: I/DEBUG(343):     ip 9ecf9c04  sp 9ee00728  lr ab3a1c0d  pc ab39e0ae  cpsr 200f0030
03-18 12:41:26.405: I/DEBUG(343): backtrace:
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #00 pc 005c40ae  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (CPPStruct::UpdateExtBehavior(char const*, char const*)+545)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #01 pc 005c42a1  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (CPPStruct::CPPextension(yystypepp*)+232)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #02 pc 005c60dd  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (CPPStruct::DispatchCPPline(yystypepp*, int)+696)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #03 pc 005c8a6f  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (YYParser::GetLexToken(char*, unsigned int)+150)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #04 pc 005c0bd5  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (yy2_input(char*, int, TParseContext*)+12)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #05 pc 005c0d27  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #06 pc 005c212d  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (yy2lex(YYSTYPE*, TParseContext&)+3968)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #07 pc 005bb0a5  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (yy2parse(TParseContext&)+328)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #08 pc 005c0e9d  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (yy2PaYYParse(TParseContext&)+16)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #09 pc 005c8981  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (YYParser::ParseStrings(char**, long*, int, TParseContext&, int)+276)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #10 pc 005975b9  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (ShCompile+1316)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #11 pc 005405cb  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (LLVMCompiler::parse(QGLC_SRCSHADER*)+1094)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #12 pc 0054380d  /system/vendor/lib/libllvm-glnext.so (CompilerContext::CompileToIRShader(QGLC_SRCSHADER*, QGLC_COMPILETOIR_RESULT*)+168)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #13 pc 000f7ead  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxShaderCompiler::CompileShader(EsxShader const*, EsxInfoLog*)+476)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #14 pc 000f6a09  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxShader::Compile(EsxContext*)+68)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #15 pc 000a8951  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlCompileShader(unsigned int)+60)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #16 pc 000d9cc1  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlApiParamValidate::GlCompileShader(EsxDispatch*, unsigned int)+40)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #17 pc 0009fc13  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glCompileShader+26)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #18 pc 0130c308  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #19 pc 0130bb28  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #20 pc 0130b85c  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #21 pc 011e5614  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #22 pc 0130831c  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #23 pc 01308978  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #24 pc 01308160  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #25 pc 01113a0c  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #26 pc 011137e8  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #27 pc 0111353c  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #28 pc 0169a8bf  [REDACTED]
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #29 pc 000162e3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
03-18 12:41:26.406: I/DEBUG(343):     #30 pc 000142d3  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
```

**Device details**

Model Number: Nexus 6
Build Number: LRX210
OpenGL version: OpenGL ES 3.0V@95.0 (GIT@I86da836d38)
OpenGL renderer: Adreno (TM) 420
GLSL version: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.10
supported extensions: GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_framebuffer_object GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr GL_OES_texture_npot GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_OES_texture_3D GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_EXT_sRGB GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_float_linear GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_EXT_copy_image GL_EXT_geometry_shader GL_EXT_tessellation_shader GL_OES_texture_stencil8 GL_EXT_shader_io_blocks GL_OES_shader_image_atomic GL_OES_sample_variables GL_EXT_texture_border_clamp GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_OES_shader_multisample_interpolation GL_EXT_draw_buffers_indexed GL_EXT_gpu_shader5 GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_buffer GL_OES_texture_storage_multisample_2d_array GL_OES_sample_shading GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_EXT_debug_label GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_ANDROID_extension_pack_es31a GL_EXT_primitive_bounding_box GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_debug

**Repro vertex shader**

```
attribute highp vec4 Pos;
uniform mat4 ModelViewProj;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = ModelViewProj * Pos;
}
```

**Repro fragment shader**

```
#if GL_OES_standard_derivatives
#   extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif // GL_OES_standard_derivatives

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My main observation of the problem is that by looking at the gl details, I have a GL version of 3.0 and GLSL of 3.1, which doesn't sound like it should be possible. I've built a work around where I check the OpenGL version and load a shader that doesn't have the extension code to try and compensate for it. I then just hard-code some values in place of the extension code. It works for the type of shader I'm using but I can imagine there will be cases for others where there is no suitable values to use.
However, after releasing the game the same callstack is being reported through google play from other devices (Samsung Galaxy Note4/S5 on Android 5.0 & Nexus 6 on Android 5.1) which I don't currently have access to.

Edit: found an actual solution to the problem.

The #if check for the extension macro is incorrect, the should be checked with #ifdef or #if defined().
This code will compile correctly and not cause a crash:

```
#ifdef GL_OES_standard_derivatives
#   extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif // GL_OES_standard_derivatives

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

From the [GLSL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf), pg 12:

> #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #else, #elif, and #endif are defined to operate as for C++ except for the following:
>
> - Expressions following #if and #elif are restricted to expressions operating on literal integer constants, plus identifiers consumed by the defined operator.
> - Undefined identifiers not consumed by the defined operator do not
>     default to '0'. Use of such identifiers causes an error.
> - Character constants are not supported.

As a note however during some experiments I found the following code would fail to compile but would not crash during glCompileShader:

```
#if GL_OES_standard_derivatives
//#   extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
#endif // GL_OES_standard_derivatives

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Do all of the affected devices use GPUs from the same vendor?

Comment: Yes, the Snapdragon 805. The only S5 variant we get crashes for is the Korean LTE-A which is the only S5 to use the 805. Not sure what we do with this information now though...